# Как вывести в адаптере для ImageView URL картинки

Tags: java, android

Есть адаптер -

```java
         phones.add(new Phone ("от 1", "до 500", R.drawable.kartinka, "likelook"));
```

Сам phones имеет следующий вид:

```java
public class Phone {

    private String name;
    private String company;
    private int image;
    private String clickbutton;


    public Phone(String name, String company, int image, String clickbutton){

        this.name=name;
        this.company = company;
        this.image = image;
        this.clickbutton = clickbutton;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getCompany() {
        return this.company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getClickbutton(){
        return this.clickbutton;
    }

    public void setClickbutton(){
        this.clickbutton = clickbutton;
    }
}
```

Всё классно работает но мне нужно чтобы я могу поставить за место R.drawable.kartinka - URl картинки, например - https://frescolib.org/static/logo.png

Как это правильно реализовать? Спасибо! В данном коде..

Comment: Вам надо добавить ещё одно поле с сеттерами и геттерами для строки-URL. После этого переписать логику установки картинки через либу Glide.

Comment: а можете показать как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте поле в Phone `private String url;`
Если ссылка заранее не известна присвойте полю null `private String url = null`

Точно так же заполняйте поля вашего Phone

`phones.add(new Phone ("от 1", "до 500", "https://frescolib.org/static/logo.png", R.drawable.kartinka, "likelook"));`

Добавьте библиотеку для работы с картинками, например Glide. В вашем build.gradle в разделе

```
dependencies { 
   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1' 
}
```

Могу предположить ,что поскольку у вас массив данных, вы захотите отображать эти данные списком. Ознакомьтесь с ListAdapter или с RecyclerView(смотрите примеры)
В удобном вам месте, где есть доступ к view элемента списка, например в адаптере или в случаи использования RecyclerView в холдере или в методе onBindViewHolder. Сделайте следующее.

```
Glide.with(ваша view списка)
            .load(game.getUrl) //ваша url  
            .error(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp) //покажет эту картинку в случаи отсутствия интернета
            .into(imageView);
```

Удачи вам, спрашивайте если возникнут вопросы